# Can't find the config/packages/api_platform.yaml on Symfony 6

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony6

After installing the API platform on my Symfony 6.2 project using the composer command `composer require API`

I can't find the api_platform.yaml file in `config/packages` folders, the only file related to API-PLATFORM I found is on the `routes` directory

Is this a new update? Or should I add it in a certain way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to

> config/packages/

2. Create

> api_platform.yaml

3. Add your configuration

> ```
> api_platform:
>   title: 'MY API'
> ```

4. Restart the Symfony Dev Server

> ```
> symfony server:stop
> symfony server:start
> ```

Check https://localhost:8000/api/docs to see the results.

Comment: And you can run `composer install` too